# How to create a dynamic page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'd like to list some components in a row and when a component reaches the end of the page it should just move to the next row. In this way I expect the page to be adjusted dynamically to the size of the screen. I don’t have a code example because it’s a theoretical question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the screen width/height to calculate the size of the row widgets.

To get the screen size do the following:

```dart
final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

`final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;`

// or you can use screen util package it make your screen responsive

and make your code inside `SizedBox` 
it will work

like this :
 `SizedBox( height: 100, width: width * 0.85 // this mean width is 85% of screen width// child: //your code ),`

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html).  Give it some children, and it lays them out by default start to end horizontally, and when the next child doesn't fit, it starts a second line.

You don't even need to put it in a row, but you can certainly use it as part of a row or part of a column.